# Laravel Eloquent, get all datas in ids array with whereIn?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Here my code :

```
$search = request()->get('search');
    $conciergerieSelect = request()->get('conciergerie');

    $services = Service::get();

    $prestations = Prestation::with([
        'service:name'
    ])
    ->whereIn('conciergerie_ids', $conciergerieSelect)
    ->where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i")
    ->paginate(100);

    return $res = [
        'prestations' => $prestations,
        'services' => $services
    ];
```

I need to get all prestations where there is an `conciergerie_ids` equal to `$conciergerieSelect`.

`conciergerie_ids` is a table of ids.

`$conciergerieSelect` is an id.

I tried to use whereIn but i get an error : "Invalid supplied foreach()"
Thank you.

Comment: Make sure conciergerie_ids is column in prestations table not a table of ids and $conciergerieSelect is array of ids

Comment: for uisng whereIn('conciergerie_ids', $conciergerieSelect) conciergerie_ids is your column name and $conciergerieSelect will be array of ids

Comment: you are getting Invalid supplied foreach()  this error because $conciergerieSelect is not an array

Comment: Thank you very much it's okay now !

Comment: @Tony if you have now working code consider posting it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `whereIn` method provided by Laravel accepts an array as the 2nd parameter.

Please replace the `$conciergerieSelect` variable by `[$conciergerieSelect]` in the `whereIn` clause:

```
//...
->whereIn('conciergerie_ids', [$conciergerieSelect])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the working code with your help :

```
$search = request()->get('search');
$conciergerieSelect = request()->get('conciergerie');

$services = Service::get();

$prestations = Prestation::with([
    'service:name'
])
->whereIn('conciergerie_ids', [$conciergerieSelect]) <-- 
->where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i")
->paginate(100);

return $res = [
    'prestations' => $prestations,
    'services' => $services
];
```